# How do i eliminate files saved in Run/user/1000/doc

Tags: permissions, files, snap, delete

I run Ubuntu 22.04.
My web browsers saves downloaded files to the run/user/1000/doc folder in hex-named folders created for every single file. As I learned seaching the web, this can be avoided by installing the webbrowsers directly instead via Snapstore. It seems that Snap-installed apps are allowed to use only run/user/1000/doc or their sandbox folder to write files, so this explains why I can't change the download folder to one of my choice.
But looking at the run/user/1000/doc folder and displaying the details I see more than 600 GB of files that I assume are filling up my SSD. When I want to mark all the subfolders for removal I don't even get a "remove" item on the dropdown context menu.

How can I remove safely the folders and files that piled up over the years without a full system reinstall (like in Windows)? Or are these links to the actual files stored elswhere? But the download of the brower files to the specific location suggests they are not only images but actual files.

Comment: The command gives me `TARGET         SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/run/user/1000 tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1209436k,nr_inodes=302359,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64`

Comment: Did you try to change the download folder? All my Firefox installation via snap save dowloaded files to ~/Downloads by default (=without an changes after installation).
snaps use indeed a sandbox with limited file system access, but the home directory of the current user can typically accessed. 
Folder under /run are created and runtime and are deleted at reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your exported flatpak documents found in `/run/user/1000/doc` by using the following command:

```bash
flatpak documents | xargs -n1 flatpak document-unexport --doc-id
```

`/run/user/1000/doc` is not a tmpfs. Its mount entry should look like `portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)` . The type `fuse.portal` means that the files don't reside in memory, but are rather virtual files that will redirect to actual files elsewhere on your system. This is used for controlling sandboxed apps' access to files. You must have opened 600GB of files in 1 sandboxed application, or something like opened 200GB of the same files in 3 sandboxed applications.